# HeapifyJava priorityQueue

Tags: java, data-structures, heap, priority-queue

I am using `PriorityQueue` for having Heap Data Structure in my code. I wan't to find customer with lowest `cost`. Cost of the customers might change during the execution. So I have maintained a heap of all customers. I was trying following code - (Output is indicated in the comments)

```
    PriorityQueue<Customer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>();
    Customer c1 = new Customer(10);
    Customer c2 = new Customer(20);
    Customer c3 = new Customer(3);
    Customer c4 = new Customer(40);
    pq.add(c1);pq.add(c2);pq.add(c3);pq.add(c4);

    System.out.println(pq.peek() == c3); //Prints true

    c1.cost = 1;

    System.out.println(pq.peek() == c1); //Prints false
```

Though the state of object `c1` is changed, Heap didn't get Heapified. Basically I want both the lines to output `true`. I didn't find any javadoc help for explicitly Heapifying the Heap. Can somebody please help, how can I do/tweak this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to remove and re-insert the object to the PriorityQueue after the update. Priority queue works by putting new elements in the appropriate position when they are inserted and no updates are taken into account.

Comment: As far as I can see it, this is correct. However, this is NOT how a priority queue *should* work. Updating a given element in the heap merely requires one heapUp/heapDown operation for that element (depending on whether the key increased or decreased), with runtime in O(log n). the `remove` call, however, takes time O(n) for *locating* the element to remove... this arguably defeats the purpose of using a binary heap in the first place.